# Save the path history to the radio button

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am designing an R Shiny app, and I have been able to display the selected file name back to the radio button.

However, I have tried many methods, including getting help from an AI bot, but they have not been successful. I want to be able to visualize the data again after clicking on the radio button with the file name, without having to select the file again from the beginning. Here is my server.R code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)

selectedFileNames <- reactiveVal(character(0))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    selectedFileName <- input$file$name

    if (!(selectedFileName %in% selectedFileNames())) {
      selectedFileNames(c(selectedFileNames(), selectedFileName))
    }
    
    read.csv(input$file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })
  
  observe({
    updateRadioButtons(session, "selectedOption", choices = c("", selectedFileNames()), selected = input$selectedOption)
  })
  
  
  filteredData <- reactive({
    data_filtered <- data()
    date_range <- input$dateRange
    if (!is.null(date_range)) {
      start_date <- as.POSIXct(date_range[1], format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC")
      end_date <- as.POSIXct(date_range[2], format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC")
      data_filtered <- data_filtered %>%
        filter(between(as.POSIXct(Start.Time), start_date, end_date))
    }
    data_filtered
  })
  
  output$userSearchPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filteredData(), aes(x = as.Date(Start.Time), fill = factor(User))) +
      geom_bar() +
      labs(title = "Number of User Searches Over Time",
           x = "Date",
           y = "Number of Searches",
           fill = "User") +
      theme_minimal() +
      scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d", date_breaks = "1 day") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
  })
  
  output$summaryText <- renderPrint({
    summary_data <- filteredData() %>%
      group_by(date = as.Date(Start.Time)) %>%
      summarise(NumUsers = n_distinct(User), NumSearches = n()) %>%
      as.data.frame()
    
    summary_label <- "Summary of User Searches Over Time"

    colnames(summary_data) <- c("Date", "Number of User", "Number of Searcher")

    cat(summary_label, "\n")
    print(summary_data)
  })
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please list some of the "many methods" you have tried, as we would prefer to avoid repeating the effort you have already put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the uploaded datasets in a reactive list (`reactiveValues`) and access this list when the user selects a radio button.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  selectedFileNames <- reactiveVal(character(0))
  
  Datasets <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    selectedFileName <- input$file$name
    
    if (!(selectedFileName %in% selectedFileNames())) {
      selectedFileNames(c(selectedFileNames(), selectedFileName))
    }
    
    dat <- read.csv(input$file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    Datasets[[selectedFileName]] <- dat
  })
  
  observeEvent(selectedFileNames(), {
    currentFileName <- selectedFileNames()[length(selectedFileNames())]
    updateRadioButtons(
      session, "selectedOption", choices = c("", selectedFileNames()), 
      selected = currentFileName
    )
  })
  
  data <- eventReactive(input$selectedOption, {
    Datasets[[input$selectedOption]]
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  ......
  
}
```